# Q&A Tree On Topic

Tags: discussion, scope, faq-proposed

I was thinking about starting a little Q&A tree because I want to give something back to the community.  It would be on Qt Gui since I am going through the process of learning it(I would provide most the answers also).  I wanted to know if there would be a problem with this?

**Example:**

**(Q)** What type of Qt Gui items are there?

**(A)** Qt Gui has the following items: (*Links to Other Stack Q&A Trees*)

1. Label
2. Text Area
3. Button
4. Window
5. Check Box
6. etc....

**From Linked Q&A:** (*Visits "Text Area" link*)

**(Q)** What types of labels are there, and what can I do with them?

**(A)** The following label types exist with format options:

QLabel (*Linked to current Qt documentation ref*)

1. Round Borders (*Links to "How can I round QLabel Corners?"*)
2. etc....

And so on. And so on.

Comment: Some more context please - in particular, what's this got to do with the Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: These are questions and answers that I found particularly hard to put together.  And I guess it has to do with SO because they are q&a sits.

Comment: Fine. What's that got to do with us? I don't quite understand what the point of this "Q&A tree" is - it certainly didn't come across. In other words - what problem is this supposed to solve and for whom?

Comment: I believe he wants to post a question like "What type of Qt GUI items are there?" (would likely get closed), and then, in the answer, list all of the types, each of which is a link to a question about that type of item. Basically reproduce the documenatation with commentary?

Comment: If I had a question on rounding QlineEdit corners or how to edit its width.  Those are questions on programming with Qt if I am not mistaken.  Never mind, it already sounds like more hassle to help then its worth to get grief on helping down the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This idea, in general, wouldn't work, because the top-level questions would tend towards "list-of" questions, which are off-topic. "How can I round QLabel Corners?" sounds a bit more on-topic, as it a addresses a specific issue, but "What types of labels are there, and what can I do with them?" is both a "list-of" question and open-ended (there are a lot of things you can do with them, depends how creative/hacky you want to get).

So while there isn't really anything against this concept in [the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), most of the questions holding the thing together wouldn't be able to stand on their own as questions on StackOverflow.